# Styled-components extends props

Tags: reactjs, styled-components

I have a ready button like this , These are the features I want every button to have.

If I send props for the icon, I don't want the icon to be created, if I don't, I don't want it to be created.

```
    import Icon from 'components/icons/Icon';
import styled from 'styled-components';

const Button = styled.button`
  border-radius: 8px;
  color: white;
  cursor: pointer;
  outline: none;
  border: none;
  display: flex;
  font-family: 'DM Sans', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 700;
`;

const DefaultButton = ({ name, children }) => {
  return (
    <Button>
      {name && <Icon name={name}></Icon>}
      {children}
    </Button>
  );
};

export default DefaultButton;
```

I have a button component that I have customized like this.
I want it to inherit its properties from the default button.
But Primary's features do not appear on my button.
I wonder what should I fix, thanks friend

```
import styled from 'styled-components';
import { sizes } from 'constants/components/button';
import { colors } from 'theme';
import DefaultButton from './DefaultButton';

const PrimaryButton = styled(DefaultButton)`
  padding: ${({ size }) => sizes[size]} 48px;
  background-color: ${colors.primary.color};
  font-size: 14px;
  font-style: bold;

  &:focus {
    border: 1px solid #ffffff;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px 3px rgba(24, 207, 152, 1);
  }
  &:hover {
    background-color: ${colors.primary.pressed};
    box-shadow: 0px 14px 24px rgba(23, 207, 151, 0.3);
    color: white;
  }

  &:disabled {
    background-color: ${colors.primary.disabled};
    cursor: not-allowed;
    pointer-events: none;
    color: white;
  }
`;

export default PrimaryButton;
```

This is how I use my component and I want it to be like this

```
<PrimaryButton size="md" name="test">
        Sign in
      </PrimaryButton>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to extend/override the styles of another component, you need to pass down the `className` prop, as mentioned in the [docs](https://styled-components.com/docs/basics#styling-any-component).

> The styled method works perfectly on all of your own or any third-party component, as long as they attach the passed className prop to a DOM element.

```
const DefaultButton = ({ name, children, className }) => {
  return (
    <Button className={className}>
      {name && <Icon name={name}></Icon>}
      {children}
    </Button>
  );
};
```

Comment: but i don't send classname how can i do

Comment: `className` is an implicit prop that gets passed to components. Just destructure it from the props and pass it down. 
I've implemented a simple example in this [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/focused-architecture-t1wxu?file=/src/DefaultButton.js)

Answer (score 0):

I find @svrbst solution very effective. I extended it to add other dependencies as shown is the question and it works fine. Here is the forked [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/delicate-bash-cpy61?file=/src/PrimaryButton.js)